# javascript node socket game wait for ALL users in room to respond

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I am making a game in node with web sockets where the server sends a question to the members of the current room.
I then need it to wait until all the users have responded with an answer before it moves on to the next question (I don't want anyone to know the next question before anyone else).

I think I can have a global var server side that I incrememnt on every `client.on('join'...` so that I know how many users are in the room. Can I do the same for when a user has responded, i.e

```
var countResponses = 0;

client.on('responds', function(d) {
countResponses += 1;
//do something with d
if (countResponses == numUsers) {
//...
}
});
```

Is this the recommended way to do this kind of thing? Feels like its going to get quite bulky very quickly...